# Arp request is not resolved

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ping, arp, host

On my machine, I have assigned ip addresses for two interfaces which are connected through a cable. They are connected with 10G ports.

When i tried to ping the two addresses, ping was not working. later on my analysis i found that the arp request is not resolved.

The arp table entry for that ip is shown incomplete.

I could not understand why the arp request is not resolved.

Please help me with this..

Here is the arp request and tcpdump logs

## arp

Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
169.254.0.27             ether   00:a0:a5:65:03:b4   C                     bond0
169.254.0.29             ether   00:a0:a5:65:03:b4   C                     bond0
169.254.0.41             ether   00:a0:a5:65:03:b4   C                     bond0
169.254.0.18             ether   00:d0:c9:d7:09:86   C                     bond0
**5.5.5.1                          (incomplete)                              vlan_ab**
169.254.0.4              ether   00:a0:a5:65:03:b4   C                     bond0
169.254.0.31             ether   00:a0:a5:65:03:b4   C                     bond0
169.254.0.39             ether   00:a0:a5:65:03:b4   C                     bond0
169.254.0.32             ether   00:a0:a5:65:03:b4   C                     bond0
169.254.0.49             ether   00:a0:a5:65:03:b4   C                     bond0

## tcpdump -vvv -ni vlan_ab

tcpdump: listening on vlan_ab, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes

**10:28:49.844237 arp who-has 5.5.5.1 tell 5.5.5.2
10:28:50.844238 arp who-has 5.5.5.1 tell 5.5.5.2
10:28:51.844235 arp who-has 5.5.5.1 tell 5.5.5.2**

Comment: Have you ran a packet capture with tcpdump or wireshark, if so, providing the output of that would be most useful. Is iptables configured? Can you show us the configuration of this also please? How can you configured the IPs, can you show us the configuration of this also? Lots more information would help!

Comment: Did you doublecheck the cabling/speed/half/full duplex setting?

Comment: @javano . Please find the logs attached

Comment: @KamilŠrot : Please find the logs attached

Comment: Have still the same opinion - check wiring. The arp entry with MAC showing "incomplete" means nothing - it'll show up for any local IP you try to reach even if it's not set on any computer in your local net

Comment: SO, looking at your logs, do you have two 10Ge interfaces in a bond group as bond0?

Comment: Also, why do you have multiple link local IP ARP entries for that bond interface? I'm starting to suspect you haven't configured that interface correctly.